# How much internet traffic does a 3.5GH/sec pooled miner use?

Tags: mining-pools, bandwidth

The question is clear I think. I used 3.5GH/s because that's what the upcoming ButterflyLabs Jalapeno will run. **Assume it's mining for an average mining pool with 3.5GH/s** (only bitcoins).

I'm interested in maintaining one on a spot where I can get electricity for free, but I have limited internet access.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/360/516

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internet traffic for any miner is generally minimal and in most cases the miner speed is irrelevant. The [Getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork) protocol would at most make a small request every second, but with extensions such as rollntime, one can make the request less frequently. You can roughly see how much data is being sent from the examples provided [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=51281.msg611856#msg611856). Generally, you shouldn't worry about the internet speed or bandwidth.

Comment: Isn't there any estimate per 24h available or so?

Comment: Well under 100MB per day.  http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=82865.msg913908#msg913908