# Bandwidth speed for Bitcoin mining?

Tags: mining-setup, bandwidth

I think to setup an ASIC Ant Miner in my university apartment.
I am new to Bitcoin mining and since the university network does block any Bitcoin related connections I was thinking to use my smartphone 3G internet for this purpose. 
 But now I wonder what bandwidth speed will I need to maintain 24/7 mining process without any bandwidth speed issues.

Comment: What about using a VPN to get around the university blocking?

Comment: as an option yes.

Comment: OK guys ,i would like to excuse ,becaue i found exactly same question ,and here is the question and a great answer : http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/360/what-are-the-bandwidth-requirements-of-a-mining-rig?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I think your 3G speeds should work pretty well. They usually do not require fast internet connections.

Comment: does the bandwith increase exponentialy if i will increase the quantity of my mining devices ?