# How much internet traffic and bandwidth does mining with a pool need?

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining, bandwidth

As you know the new Antminer S9 is available and its hash rate per second is 14TH.
Now, my question is if I buy one of these, how much internet traffic and bandwidth do I need for mining by pool and how much for solo mining (and is it different for two machines or so).

Comment: This question should help you: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/360/what-are-the-bandwidth-requirements-of-a-mining-rig

Comment: Solo mining is not realistic at this point for small-scale mining operations. An S9 at the current difficulty could expect to find one block every two years solo mining, under ideal conditions. The reality is the difficulty will increase at a pace sufficient to ensure you never find a block.

Answer (score 2):

1 Meg Internet can connect 150 S9.  1S9 could use upto 300M per month of data

Comment: One would think that every time a new block is found all miners need to start mining on the next block. How do miners avoid downloading the whole 2MB block every 10 minutes?